# What is this parsing notation called?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> This is a sentence.
>
> [<sub>S</sub> [<sub>NP</sub> This] [<sub>VP</sub> [<sub>V</sub> is] [<sub>NP</sub> [<sub>D</sub> a] [<sub>N</sub> sentence]]]]

(The abbreviations of the categories are usually in subscript.)

These seem to be used a lot in constituency grammars.

E.g.

[image]

"Bracket notation", maybe?

Comment: There's no special name for it, except maybe "using brackets" (or "parentheses"). There are tree-drawing programs that take notation like this as input, but they're hard on human perception. The same problems arise whenever a linear string notation like literacy has to cope with representing a hierarchical phenomenon unambiguously. See [the Logic Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for details, and even more in [the VP guide](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), if you're a glutton for representation.

Comment: May be a **bracketing structure** (*it's always possible to state a bracketing structure as a tree, and vice versa*). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketing_(linguistics)

Answer (score 6):

[As *The Utrecht Lexicon of Linguistics* explains,](https://lexicon.hum.uu.nl/?lemma=Labeled+bracketing&lemmacode=577&lemma=Labeled+bracketing&lemmacode=577) this notation is known as **labeled bracketing.** This is defined as:

> A way of representing the structure of an expression by writing square brackets ('[' and ']') to the left and right hand side of its component parts, i.e. words or constituents. The brackets carry subscripts, so-called labels, which state the category of the unit in question.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> There's no special name for it, except maybe "using brackets" (or "parentheses"). There are tree-drawing programs that take notation like this as input, but they're hard on human perception. The same problems arise whenever a linear string notation like literacy has to cope with representing a hierarchical phenomenon unambiguously. See [the Logic Guide](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/logicguide.pdf) for details, and even more in [the VP guide](http://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/VPguide.pdf), if you're a glutton for representation.